# Special characters on AngularJS + Ionic

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, ionic-framework

The views of AngularJS are set as utf-8:
[code Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlIBF.png), 
but I can't make my characters like áóíé works in one of my views (not everyone). Code of that view:

```
<ion-view title="Informaciones">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header padding-content" scroll="false">
        <a href="" onclick="window.open('some url', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
            <div class="card card-button">
                <i class="icon icon-bg bg-energized ion-information"></i>
                <h3>Términos de Uso</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here works fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNyB.png)

Comment: Just a guess, but try to check if the document itself is saved in utf-8.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that others tab of the app has the special characters working correct.

Comment: Maybe the font doesn't support these characters? try changing the font for that HTML tag to a different font